# Splitting DD:MM:YYYY Hr:mm:ss column in two columns in R

Tags: r

My data frame has 2 columns with several hundred rows :
**Product Name** : Describes the product sold, **character** & 
**Delivery timeline** : Describes when was product was delivered 21-04-2017 10:00:00, Character.
I need to split the Delivery timeline column into two columns:-
Date  : to contain DD-MM-YYYY , date format
Time : hr:mm:ss, time format.
This has to be done for all rows of the columns.
Can someone help with exact commands, I did try but not able to achieve the derived columns.

Comment: Please you should include a reproducible example together with some data, in order to help the readers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: I would recommend against splitting your column.  R does not handle times very well.  I would use the as.POSIXct function and convert the character strings to a date/time object which can then be formatted for output or used in further analysis.

Answer (score 0):

```
 dat=data.frame(time=rep(Sys.time(),10)+10001:10010,stringsAsFactors = F)

 dat
                   time
 1  2017-12-22 18:31:27
 2  2017-12-22 18:31:28
 3  2017-12-22 18:31:29
 4  2017-12-22 18:31:30
 5  2017-12-22 18:31:31
 6  2017-12-22 18:31:32
 7  2017-12-22 18:31:33
 8  2017-12-22 18:31:34
 9  2017-12-22 18:31:35
10 2017-12-22 18:31:36

 proto=data.frame(date=character(), time=character())
 strcapture("(\\w.*)\\s(\\w.*)",as.character(A$time),proto)

          date     time
 1  2017-12-22 18:31:27
 2  2017-12-22 18:31:28
 3  2017-12-22 18:31:29
 4  2017-12-22 18:31:30
 5  2017-12-22 18:31:31
 6  2017-12-22 18:31:32
 7  2017-12-22 18:31:33
 8  2017-12-22 18:31:34
 9  2017-12-22 18:31:35
 10 2017-12-22 18:31:36
```